# Can't understand function (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++(I have experience with C, though) and can't understand this function.
My problem is specifically with the line:
`std::tuple<std::string,std::string> tmp( protein[i], protein[i+order]) ;`

Could someone explain it to me?

```
std::vector< std::tuple< std::string,std::string > > domPairSet(std::vector<std::string> protein, int order ) {
    /*
    Create a set of domain pair of a specified order from a protein
    \param protein1
    \param order
    \return pairsOfDom
    */
    std::vector< std::tuple< std::string,std::string > > pairsOfDom ;    
    int cnt;    
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < protein.size( ) - order ; i ++ ) {
        std::tuple<std::string,std::string> tmp( protein[i], protein[i+order]) ;
        cnt = std::count( pairsOfDom.begin(), pairsOfDom.end(), tmp ) ; 
        if ( cnt == 0 )
            pairsOfDom.push_back( tmp );
    }
    return pairsOfDom ;
}
```

Comment: It creates and initializes a variable named `tmp`. The type is `std::tuple<std::string,std::string>` which in simple words means "a pair of strings".

Comment: You'll want to read up on C++ -- maybe take an online programming tutorial or two -- before trying to understand code in it. It's not a language that can be parsed without much instruction.

Comment: The question title and the bioinformatics tag are both irrelevant to the question. (Much like 'Sherlock Holmes' is irrelevant to the purpose of a full stop at the end of a sentence in a mystery novel novel you happen to be reading.) Please [edit] your question to ask about whatever it is that's really puzzling you. I'd guess something to do with [tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), but I can't read your mind to tell for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::tuple<std::string,std::string> tmp(protein[i], protein[i+order]);
```

[std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is a class template that is a fixed-size collection of values of arbitrary types.

So, `std::tuple<std::string, std::string> tmp` creates a variable of tuple type, which holds two elements of `std::string` type.

Finally, the `(protein[i], protein[i+order]);` part calls the tuple constructor and passes the values to the elements of the tuple.

So after this line you will have a tuple with 2 elements of `string` type, with values `protein[i]` and `protein[i+order]`.